# obtaining value corresponding to a row from csv dataset

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am trying to retrieve a value from a CSV dataset corresponding to an index (another attribute in the dataset) but I keep getting the `error  index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`.

I read the data set as

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("df.csv",encoding='latin1',low_memory=False)
```

and the function which is supposed to returns the title in my case is,

```
def get_index_from_title(name):
    # print(name)
    return dataset[dataset.name == name]["index"].values[0]
```

the name has a certain value as shown in the screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZMoF.png)

How can I retrieve the index for the name of "HelloWorld" for example? I Would really appreciate some kind of assistance.

The code was adapted from a YouTube tutorial here: https://youtu.be/XoTwndOgXBM to learn

Comment: It means that the DataFrame does not contain any rows with your selected "name". Hence its empty.

Comment: @SuhasMucherla Hi , There is an attribute called name in the dataset and the value is also available howeve

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct if index is a column in your dataframe:

```
index = [0,1,2]
name = ["HelloWorld", "name1", "name2"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'index':index, 'name':name})

df[df.name == "HelloWorld"]["index"].values[0]
```

In this case, the dataframe looks like this:

```
   index        name
0      0  HelloWorld
1      1       name1
2      2       name2
```

But if index is not a column name, but the actual index of rows, that method would not work. You should try this:

```
index = [0,1,2]
name = ["HelloWorld", "name1", "name2"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'index':index, 'name':name})

df.set_index('index', inplace = True)
df[df.name == "HelloWorld"].index[0]
```

Here the dataframe looks like:

```
             name
index            
0      HelloWorld
1           name1
2           name2
```

Comment: Hi but index is actually a column name in the data set.

Comment: The attached screen shot will clarify the doubt :)

Comment: Then please check that the name you are giving to your function is exactly same as the name in the column data. get_index_from_title("HelloWorld"). Also please check in your dataframe for any prior or post spaces in the HelloWorld text, it could have been " HelloWorld" or "HelloWorld ", it wouldnt match the == condition and throw that error then. Thanks :)